# Convert decimal format to string with specified format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to convert decimal to string in some specific format

```
1.0 to "+01:00"
-4.0 to "-04:00"
```

I have used `.toString()`  but that is only converting to string as expected how to convert it into above format. Please suggest

Comment: is it always 0 after the decimal point

Comment: @cmgchess Yes always

Comment: So what part of this "problem" aren't you able to solve then? A simple `< 0` check to determine whether you need to output `+` or `-` for the sign, isn't exactly rocket science ... And how to output a number zero-filled from the left is anything but a new problem, but something you should be able to quickly research yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function to convert number to your desired format using `padStart` and `toFixed`.

```js
const format = num => {
  const sign = num > 0 ? '+' : '-';
  const [first, second] = num.toFixed(2).split('.');
  return `${sign}${first.replace('-','').padStart(2, '0')}:${second}`
}
console.log(format(1.0))  // "+01:00"
console.log(format(-4.0)) // "-04:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const convert = (val) => {
  const plusMinus = val > 0 ? '+' : '-';
  const decimal = val.toFixed(2).replace(/\./, ':').replace(/^-/, '');
  const prefixedZero = val < 10 && val > -10 ? '0': '';
  return `${plusMinus}${prefixedZero}${decimal}`
}

console.log(convert(1.0))
console.log(convert(-4))
console.log(convert(0))
console.log(convert(-10))
   console.log(convert(10))
```

Comment: After + or minus 0 should be there like "+01:00". But in your solution it is +1:00

Comment: @user13000875 - ah yes good point. Just updated with prefixedZero